# Physical motivation behind the result $\mathbf {\frac12} \otimes \mathbf 1 = \mathbf { \frac 32} \oplus \mathbf { \frac 12}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

When we are considering the total angular momentum of a system with spin 1/2 and orbital angular momentum $\ell = 1$, we obtain the result that $$\mathbf {\frac12} \otimes \mathbf 1 = \mathbf { \frac 32} \oplus \mathbf { \frac 12},$$ that is the composite system can be built as the direct sum of a spin 1/2 system and a $j =\frac 32$ system. Physically one can expect to get states of $j = \frac 3 2$ when considering $J = L +S$, but why should one expect to get the subspace with $j = \frac 12$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intuitively this is just because you can have the two "angular momentum vectors" $\vec{L}$ and $\vec{S}$ pointing in opposite directions, so the resulting magnitude of $\vec{J} = \vec{L} + \vec{S}$ is the difference (rather than the sum) of the individual magnitudes for each vector separately.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: One more question: how would this explanation generalize to larger values of $\ell$ and $s$, i.e., to the general direct sum decomposition of $j_1 \otimes j_2$?

Comment: I think you should get $|j_1-j_2|\oplus (j_1+j_2)$

Comment: @DanDan0101 that's not the correct decomposition, see Shankar chapter 15.2. I think that by considering all possible orientations of $J_1$ and $J_2$ that one could possibly obtain these results, but by orientation I assume that we are talking about the orientations of the vectors $\langle J_1\rangle$ and $\langle J_2\rangle$.

Comment: @DanielWaters My bad, you're totally right

Comment: @DanDan0101 No problem

Comment: @DanielWaters maybe you have already figured it out since you cited Shankar, but in general you would get a direct sum decomposition containing all values of angular momentum ranging from $|j_1-j_2|$ to $j_1+j_2$, all equally spaced by $1$ unit. The reason why you get these two extremes is the same as what I explained, and you can get the other values in-between by imagining that the two angular momentum vectors are not perfectly parallel or anti-parallel. Can you see why they will vary by $1$ unit (as opposed to by $1/2$)?

Comment: @BrunoDeSouzaLeão I understand where we get the extremes from, but as for the why the difference between adjacent multiplets is 1, I don’t understand.